# md-button Angularjs materials icon does not show up

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to use angularjs materials, to design my application.
I want to create a circular home button, with a home icon inside it.
HEre is what I have done:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
    <h1 class="tit">Welcome à toi!</h1>
      <md-button class="md-fab button pull-right" id="button" ui-sref="home">
      <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-home" ng-style="{color: 'white', 'font-size':'30px', height:'30px'}"> </md-icon>
    </md-button>
```

The circle is created but the icon does not show.
Can anyone tell me whats the problem please? Thank you

Comment: where are you getting the font icons from ? they are not included by default i guess

Comment: I saw it here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/button

Comment: can you try including <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> in your html head